# php Class Redis not found on mac

Tags: php, php-extension

Php version:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdI0x.png)

When I request one of the interface of my CodeIgniter project and echo phpinfo(), there is no redis extension in the message.And the project loaded the wrong version of php like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmHVz.png)

Yes I have multiple version of php in my MacOS.
Can anyone help me with this?

My project has this error msg:

```
 ERROR - 2019-01-09 04:18:05 --> Exception:Error::__set_state(array(
   'message' => 'Class \'Redis\' not found',
   'string' => '',
   'code' => 0,
   'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/application/libraries/My_Redis.php',
   'line' => 93,
   'trace' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/application/libraries/My_Redis.php',
      'line' => 51,
      'function' => '_init',
      'class' => 'My_Redis',
      'type' => '->',
      'args' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'host' => '',
          'port' => 6379,
          'password' => '',
          'timeout' => 2,
          'persistent' => 0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/application/libraries/My_Redis.php',
      'line' => 35,
      'function' => 'getInstance',
      'class' => 'My_Redis',
      'type' => '->',
      'args' => 
      array (
        0 => 'supply_chain_busi',
      ),
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/system/core/Loader.php',
      'line' => 1095,
      'function' => '__construct',
      'class' => 'My_Redis',
      'type' => '->',
      'args' => 
      array (
        0 => 'supply_chain_busi',
      ),
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/system/core/Loader.php',
      'line' => 975,
      'function' => '_ci_init_class',
      'class' => 'CI_Loader',
      'type' => '->',
      'args' => 
      array (
        0 => 'my_redis',
        1 => '',
        2 => 
        array (
          0 => 'supply_chain_busi',
        ),
        3 => 'redis',
      ),
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/system/core/Loader.php',
      'line' => 216,
      'function' => '_ci_load_class',
      'class' => 'CI_Loader',
      'type' => '->',
      'args' => 
      array (
        0 => 'My_Redis',
        1 => 
        array (
          0 => 'supply_chain_busi',
        ),
        2 => 'redis',
      ),
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/application/libraries/Tank_auth.php',
      'line' => 45,
      'function' => 'library',
      'class' => 'CI_Loader',
      'type' => '->',
      'args' => 
      array (
        0 => 'My_Redis',
        1 => 
        array (
          0 => 'supply_chain_busi',
        ),
        2 => 'redis',
      ),
    ),
    6 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/system/core/Loader.php',
      'line' => 1095,
      'function' => '__construct',
      'class' => 'Tank_auth',
      'type' => '->',
      'args' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'website_name' => 'mycom',
          'webmaster_email' => 'webmaster@mycom.com',
          'phpass_hash_portable' => true,
          'phpass_hash_strength' => 8,
          'allow_registration' => false,
          'captcha_registration' => false,
          'email_activation' => false,
          'email_activation_expire' => 172800,
          'email_account_details' => true,
          'use_username' => true,
          'username_min_length' => 4,
          'username_max_length' => 20,
          'password_min_length' => 4,
          'password_max_length' => 20,
          'login_by_username' => true,
          'login_by_email' => true,
          'login_record_ip' => true,
          'login_record_time' => true,
          'login_count_attempts' => true,
          'login_max_attempts' => 99,
          'login_attempt_expire' => 86400,
          'autologin_cookie_name' => 'autologin',
          'autologin_cookie_life' => 2592000,
          'forgot_password_expire' => 900,
          'captcha_path' => 'captcha/',
          'captcha_fonts_path' => 'captcha/fonts/5.ttf',
          'captcha_width' => 200,
          'captcha_height' => 50,
          'captcha_font_size' => 14,
          'captcha_grid' => false,
          'captcha_expire' => 180,
          'captcha_case_sensitive' => false,
          'use_recaptcha' => false,
          'recaptcha_public_key' => '',
          'recaptcha_private_key' => '',
          'db_table_prefix' => '',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    7 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/system/core/Loader.php',
      'line' => 975,
      'function' => '_ci_init_class',
      'class' => 'CI_Loader',
      'type' => '->',
      'args' => 
      array (
        0 => 'tank_auth',
        1 => '',
        2 => 
        array (
          'website_name' => 'mycom',
          'webmaster_email' => 'webmaster@mycom.com',
          'phpass_hash_portable' => true,
          'phpass_hash_strength' => 8,
          'allow_registration' => false,
          'captcha_registration' => false,
          'email_activation' => false,
          'email_activation_expire' => 172800,
          'email_account_details' => true,
          'use_username' => true,
          'username_min_length' => 4,
          'username_max_length' => 20,
          'password_min_length' => 4,
          'password_max_length' => 20,
          'login_by_username' => true,
          'login_by_email' => true,
          'login_record_ip' => true,
          'login_record_time' => true,
          'login_count_attempts' => true,
          'login_max_attempts' => 99,
          'login_attempt_expire' => 86400,
          'autologin_cookie_name' => 'autologin',
          'autologin_cookie_life' => 2592000,
          'forgot_password_expire' => 900,
          'captcha_path' => 'captcha/',
          'captcha_fonts_path' => 'captcha/fonts/5.ttf',
          'captcha_width' => 200,
          'captcha_height' => 50,
          'captcha_font_size' => 14,
          'captcha_grid' => false,
          'captcha_expire' => 180,
          'captcha_case_sensitive' => false,
          'use_recaptcha' => false,
          'recaptcha_public_key' => '',
          'recaptcha_private_key' => '',
          'db_table_prefix' => '',
        ),
        3 => NULL,
      ),
    ),
    8 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/system/core/Loader.php',
      'line' => 216,
      'function' => '_ci_load_class',
      'class' => 'CI_Loader',
      'type' => '->',
      'args' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Tank_auth',
        1 => NULL,
        2 => NULL,
      ),
    ),
    9 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/system/core/Loader.php',
      'line' => 1178,
      'function' => 'library',
      'class' => 'CI_Loader',
      'type' => '->',
      'args' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Tank_auth',
      ),
    ),
    10 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/system/core/Loader.php',
      'line' => 152,
      'function' => '_ci_autoloader',
      'class' => 'CI_Loader',
      'type' => '->',
      'args' => 
      array (
      ),
    ),
    11 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/system/core/Controller.php',
      'line' => 51,
      'function' => 'initialize',
      'class' => 'CI_Loader',
      'type' => '->',
      'args' => 
      array (
      ),
    ),
    12 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php',
      'line' => 197,
      'function' => '__construct',
      'class' => 'CI_Controller',
      'type' => '->',
      'args' => 
      array (
      ),
    ),
    13 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/application/controllers/api/my_project.php',
      'line' => 11,
      'function' => '__construct',
      'class' => 'REST_Controller',
      'type' => '->',
      'args' => 
      array (
      ),
    ),
    14 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/system/core/CodeIgniter.php',
      'line' => 310,
      'function' => '__construct',
      'class' => 'my_project',
      'type' => '->',
      'args' => 
      array (
      ),
    ),
    15 => 
    array (
      'file' => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/index.php',
      'line' => 204,
      'args' => 
      array (
        0 => '/Users/charlie/IdeaProjects/my_project/src/system/core/CodeIgniter.php',
      ),
      'function' => 'require_once',
    ),
  ),
   'previous' => NULL,
))
```

The rest of the log is similar.It just cant find the Redis class.

Comment: _"But it still cant find the Redis class"_  what is _"it"_ in this statement? Are you getting an actual error message? If so, what is it (in full please)?

Comment: Thanks Phil.I updated my answer.I hope It's clear enough.

Comment: How are you running this and **where exactly** are you seeing the error?

Comment: My project is a CodeIgniter project.It has many controllers with many interfaces.It provides API for my android application.But when I request one of the interface in postman, the project produces these error log. My controller need to load this Redis class, but the project cant find it.

Comment: **How are you running your PHP app?**

Comment: I dont know what do you exactly mean.I start php-fpm and nginx,then I can request my interface.This project ran just well before.Then I upgraded my macos system to the lastet version,it produced this error.I guess some lib or environment may be missing.

Comment: @Phil Hi Phil,I found a problem.My phpinfo didn't show redis ext.I echo phpinfo() at the first line of my project, there is no redis in it.Apparently it loaded the wrong version php.I have multiple php installed on my MacOS.which php says the version is 7.2.10.But my project loaded the php of version 7.1.19.Do u know why?

Comment: _"my project loaded the php of version 7.1.19.Do u know why?"_ because that's the one php-fpm is loading. _"My phpinfo didn't show redis ext"_  so the screenshot at the top of your question is fake?

Comment: No it's not fake.I created a php script in my project, there is just one line echo phpinfo() in it.And it shows the picture.Now I think it may because the script doesn't need to use a php-fpm to run.Like you said,the php-fpm loaded different version of php.

Comment: install your redis in mac

Comment: And that is exactly why I asked you how you were running your PHP app.

Comment: @charlie are you using third party database cache and its called as redis ?

Comment: @Kelvin No,no ther database.Now I think it may be because of the php-fpm.I will install a new php with php-fpm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,finally I solved it.Just install it with brew:

*brew install --without-apache --with-fpm --with-mysql --with-redis --with-curl --with-intl --with-iconv php72

echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

*

I dont know if these options are right but I did have my php installed properly with all the exts I need.